# I'm encountering an issue in VuGen while attempting to substitute the server-generated value "\x2D" with "-" within the correlation value

Tags: correlation, vugen

I'm currently using LoadRunner 2022 R1 and haven't been able to successfully implement this replacement. Could anyone offer guidance on how to achieve this ?
I'm encountering an issue in VuGen while attempting to substitute the server-generated value "\x2D" with "-" within the correlation value. I'm currently using LoadRunner 2022 R1 and haven't been able to successfully implement this replacement. Could anyone offer guidance on how to achieve this replacement?
Problem is it is replacing the and trimming the value of correlation. For ex: If the correlation value sent by the server was: "ejrhyh\x2Drf9r8fhjbf", the above code would give a response as "ejrhyh-f9r8fhjbf". It would remove r or any other character which comes after D.